# pyramid structure alignment is not in place

Tags: c#, asp.net

Pyramid structure in c#. I used Environment.NewLine to break line but this not getting pyramid structure

```
        int i, j, k, n;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                Label4.Text += "";
            }
            for (k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; k++)
            {

                Label4.Text += "*";


            }
            Label4.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Comment: Just note: Your first inner loop does not make any sense.

Comment: `Label4.Text += ""` has no sense (adding *nothing*); probably it should be `Label4.Text += "*"`

Comment: @Mr.Go   my output is * *** ***** ******* , i want it in pyramid shape

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Label4.Text += "" is only for space. The code is working fine.Just an issue with alignment of *

Comment: @Neha you should mention that you're working with asp.net. your code works fine for windows forms

Comment: @fubo - ok, its web application c#.

Comment: @Neha mail me yaar, gaurav@brillbrains.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're working with asp.net you need `<br />` for line breaks and `&nbsp;` for space

```
int n;
string Pyramid = string.Empty;
n = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        Pyramid  += "&nbsp;";
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; k++)
    {
        Pyramid  += "*";
    }
    Pyramid  += "<br />";
}
Label4.Text = Pyramid;
```

Comment: it looks better. but output needs little correction           *
  ***
 *****

Comment: i think it's easier to put your text into a div which has centered horizontal text-alignment than playing around with `&nbsp;`:)

Comment: .. or display your output in a disabled multiline textbox

Comment: at this point, i'm working on my logics. i added one more &nbsp; and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

your first inner loop ,
replace this code :

```
        for (j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            Label4.Text += "";
        }
```

output :

```
*
**
***
****
```

with:

```
        for (j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            Label4.Text += " "; // just add one space in string
        }
```

output :

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
```

Comment: when i run the code   in the second line there are 3 `*` - not 2

Comment: as per her code she added a (2 * i - 1) in second loop, that's the reason , if you want just add 1 star every time then you just need to remove that "2 *"

Answer (score 0):

solution to my problem -

```
        int i, j, k, n;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                Label4.Text += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            for (k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; k++)
            {                    
                Label4.Text += "*";   
            }
            Label4.Text += "</br>";
```